# Find unused packages installed from (m)elpa but also taking on-demand loaded packages into account

Tags: use-package, list-packages

Because of playing around with some configurations I have a lot of unused but installed packages.

Can I list them somehow to know which ones I can uninstall?

The important point here is that not all packages are loaded at start. Some are loaded on demand via `use-package`.

There is a `M-x package-autoremove`. This does not take care that some packages are loaded later via `use-package`. And there are also packages listet that are definitely in use: e.g. `use-package`, `swiper`, `eglot`, ...
I also tried to use `swiper` and open a `py-file` (because of `eglot`) but the list that `package-autoremove` offers me does not change.

Maybe there is a way to tell `use-package` globally once to load everything and than do `package-autoremove`?

Answer (score 1):

You can make `use-package` load everything thusly:

```
(setq use-package-always-demand t)
```

Comment: The list becomes shorter then but there are still packages that are definitly not "unused": e.g. `swiper`, `eglot`, `use-package`, `org-roam-ui`, `company`. Even after `package-refresh-contents` and opening a `py`-file and using `swiper` the list does not become shorter anymore.

Comment: Some of these packages may have been installed in such a way that emacs thinks they are "dependencies".  The source of truth is the variable `package-selected-packages`: if a package is not listed here and is not a dependency of a package listed here, then `package-autoremove` thinks it is fair game for removal.